# DRC IMU Link not publishing transform

Tags: transforms

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We've noticed that  DRC sim 1.3 and earlier) have an IMU that is sending reasonable (yet understandably noisy) data, but there is no transform being published between the pelvis and the `imu_link`, so that data can't be used.  Currently , we are publishing a static transform every second or so between these, but we need to know (A) if this is reasonable, (B) if this will be fixed in 2.0, (C) why the `imu_link` is set to be a revolute joint in the model and not a fixed joint (goes back to (A)).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1129/drc-imu-link-not-publishing-transform/) by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) on 2013-03-15**:
As of 2.0 thi swas fixed, but as of DRCSim 2.2, this is a problem.  The AtlasPlugin tacks "pelvis" on as the link of the IMU, but apparently, the urdf stills defines the imu as living on the imu_link, which is offset from the pelvis.  So now, the imu (if you believe it's from the pelvis) is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Seems to be fixed in DRCSim 2.0

---

Originally posted by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) with karma: 86 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2